# Remake columns in pivot_table,pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I've stacked to remake a colnames. 
I pivot this dataframe.

```
from pandas import DataFrame,Series

d = {'Sex' : Series(["Male","Male","Female","Female","Female","Male"]),
      'Rank' : Series(["A","B","C","A","B","C"]),
      'Num' : Series([1,2,3,4,5,6]),
      'States' : Series(["Ohio","Oregon","NC","Michigan","NY"])
}
df = DataFrame(d)
print df
df_pvt = df.pivot_table("Num",cols=['States','Sex'],rows="Rank")
print df_pvt
```

The columns of this dataframe is ndarray.

```
print df_pvt.columns.values
type(df_pvt.columns.values)
```

I wanna remake colnames to such combined columns.

```
colnames = ['Michigan_Female','NC_Female','NY_Female','Ohio_Male','Oregon_Male']
```

I think that I have to make a func to combine these columns 
but if you know easy way to do this,please tell me any advise.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way may be to combine those columns before pivoting:

```
In [17]: df['kind'] = df.States + '_' + df.Sex

In [18]: df.pivot_table('Num', cols=['kind'], rows='Rank')
Out[18]: 
kind  Michigan_Female  NC_Female  NY_Female  Ohio_Male  Oregon_Male
Rank                                                               
A                   4        NaN        NaN          1          NaN
B                 NaN        NaN          5        NaN            2
C                 NaN          3        NaN        NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Awesome!! Add one more colmuns..I didn't notice this way. Thanks!!